# Translate TFS work item types to another language

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, tfs-power-tools

Is it possible to translate work items to another language? for example change the field "Area Path" in a PBI to our language (Hebrew) "אזור", so the resulting xml would look something like this:

```
<FIELD name="אזור" refname="System.AreaPath" type="TreePath" reportable="dimension" />
```

The problem is that whenever I try to import my changes into tfs (via witadmin) I get the following error:

"TF26177: The field System.AreaPath cannot be renamed from 'Area Path' to 'אזור'."

Can I get help please?

Answer (score 1):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms194968.aspx covers the parts that can be localized. I believe there are also language packs that might do some of this for you.

Comment: Excellent! Thanks nschonni :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, i think i have found the way to do it. I was trying to rename the field via the command "witadmin **renamewitd**...", but it should be used with the command "witadmin **changefield**..." instead. Well, at lease I hope i'm right on this one :)

Update: nschonni posted a useful link for more info.